# Equivalent of mongoose schema.pre in prisma

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, prisma

I recently switched my side project from MongoDB (mongoose) to PostgreSQL. To avoid writing raw SQL queries, I had to pick an ORM. Current options are Sequelize, TypeORM, and Prisma. I'm tending towards Prisma and have started some tutorials.

I came across an issue and I've tried google, but I haven't been able to find answers.

You know how you would normally perform certain operations before saving data to a mongo document like so

```js
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema<IUser>(
  {
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    username: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
      trim: true,
      index: true,
      lowercase: true,
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      lowercase: true,
      unique: true,
      match: /[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?/,
    },
    ....
);

userSchema.pre("save", async function (next) {
  // If the password wasn't modified, no need to regenerate the password with another salt
  if (!this.isModified("password")) return next();
  const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt();
  this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt);
  this.salt = salt;
});
```

Basically, I want to encrypt the password without having to do it in the controller. Or generally, methods to perform operations on documents like so.

```js
userSchema.methods.matchPassword = async function (rawPassword) {
  try {
    return await bcrypt.compare(rawPassword, this.password);
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error(err.message);
  }
};
```

Are these possible with Prisma? If they aren't, how do you solve common problems like this on a project with Prisma?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at this section on [Prisma middleware](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/middleware) this should fit your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Almost a year from the question but for the sake of those looking the same thing: I think mongoose schema methods can be replicated with Prisma's custom models. You can declare methods within a model. Haven't used it yet so I cannot confirm. Here are the [docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/custom-models).

For people with no patience, here's the documentation example:

```
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'

type Signup = {
  email: string
  firstName: string
  lastName: string
}

class Users {
  constructor(private readonly prisma: PrismaClient['user']) {}

  // Signup a new user
  async signup(data: Signup): Promise<User> {
    // do some custom validation...
    return this.prisma.create({ data })
  }
}

async function main() {
  const prisma = new PrismaClient()
  const users = new Users(prisma.user)
  const user = await users.signup({
    email: 'alice@prisma.io',
    firstName: 'Alice',
    lastName: 'Prisma',
  })
}
```